# Inflating views dynamically across app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, code-reuse

I have a few views used across my app, I am dynamically adding them to fragments.

The type of view is dependednt on server data so I can't use **includes** for the fragment layouts.

Each fragment can have a different composition of view e.g View 1, View 2, View 3,

```
Fragment 1 can have View 1, View 3 

Fragment 2 can have View 2, View 3
```

At the moment I'm inflating the views in each fragment but this isn't great from a design standpoint.

Whenever I make changes in one fragment I have to make them in **ALL** the other fragments.

Any design suggestions?

Comment: Hmm... You should probably look at splitting your fragments into smaller fragments (each having 1 view exactly) which do one thing well and don't overlap (if possible). Once you've managed that, you eliminate the problem of copy/paste and therefore duplicated effort in maintaining all of them if you change one. You then combine these fragments as and when needed like you already do. That's how I'd try to manage the problem if I were you but then, your question isn't very clear so this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Design-wise, a `View` is just a container inside which you represent a chosen piece of data. Which means all 3 `Views` from your example should be separate `View` instances, which share a common data to display. When the data changes, the `Views` should change.

Please mind that this is a design answer and I will not be providing any code, you have to design the implementation yourself :-)